# Get progress during blob file upload on Azure Android Storage SDK

Tags: java, android, azure, android-asynctask, azure-blob-storage

I'm using this method to upload some files on Blob (some files are large and take several minutes to upload).

```
    private void updateFilesOnBlob(){
    try {
        String timestamp = Tools.generateTimeStamp();

        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(CONTAINER_NAME);

        // Upload each file on Blob
        for (int i = 0; i< pathsArrayList.size(); i++) {
            // Define the path to a local file.
            final String filePath = pathsArrayList.get(i);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(timestamp + "/" + filenameFromPath(pathsArrayList.get(i)));
            File source = new File(filePath);
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use `blob.upload()` to start uploading the file. Is there any way to get the progress percentage?

Of course, I'm running this method into AsyncTask's `doInBackground` so it should be easy to update the UI in `onProgressUpdate()`. I just need to know the progress of the uploading process.

Answer (score 0):

@PaoloRotolo, There is a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2010/11/03/uploading-a-blob-to-azure-storage-with-progress-bar-and-variable-upload-block-size/) which introduces how to make the process bar with C# in the process of uploading blob. It's very similar with Android in Java. You can try to refer to the sample code of the blog and the [javadocs](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-android/) of Azure Storage SDK for Android to write it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [blob.CopyState.BytesCopied](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.copystate.bytescopied.aspx) and [blob.CopyState.TotalBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.copystate.totalbytes.aspx) to calculate the percentage